# Redirect to my web page by using Android Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to redirect user to specific web page after log in. I'm using Android Facebook SDK. Full internet of examples how to post on user's wall, but I couldn't find any examples or advices how to redirect for example to my app fan page. I have analyzed SDK code - Facebook.java, I saw that they're using redirect_uri parameter, so I've tried to write this parameter myself, but I got only API error code (given URL is not allowed by the App configuration) or page not found message. Maybe I can't do it by using Android Facebook SDK and I need to use different tools, api? Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this problem now.
I'm not sure also if i understood your problem fully, but if you had the same problem that led me to this page (I wanted my android-application to call the browser at a specific page) this code will do the job.

```
PeladroidLiteActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.peladroid.com")));
```